# What is the Keras concatenation output like

Tags: keras, output, concatenation, keras-layer, keras-2

I'm trying to concatenate two hidden states of a 2-Bi-LSTM layers

### but i want to know first what is the output shape of a concatenation.

Moreover, I would like to know what are the attention mechanisme. To be more explicit how can i do it for two different Bi-LSTM hidden states

Comment: Please, support your question with a minimal reproducible example

Comment: The output shape of a concatenation layer is computed this way: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/merge.py#L367